# Stop bootstrap tabs from resetting when page reloads

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, pagination

I have bootstrap tabs that call a PHP function to paginate it, the problem is, if I'm in a tab other than the active tab, if I press a different page, it reloads the page and sets me back to the active tab.

Example, I have tab a which is active by default, and tab b, which has 2 pages. If I click tab b, then press page 2, it reloads the page causing it to go back to tab a.

How can I "save" the tab that was last selected, so when the page reloads it defaults to the tab that was selected before the reload?

Edit: Here's the code for the tabs:

http://pastebin.com/rhrvFgYc

And the pagination is done with the displayFeed() method, I used this tutorial:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Comment: send a extra parameter in url of selected tab. and if it is possible please paste some code that is making problem.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code. How can I detect when a tab is changed?